# Querying Entities with maps in OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I have the following Entities

```
@Entity
public class Conversation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int Id;

    @Column
    private Alias AliasA;

    // SNIP
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Alias implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String alias;

    @Column
    private String personalName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alias", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="address")
    private Map<String, Recipient> recipients = new HashMap<String, Recipient>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Recipient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @Column
    private RecipientStatus status;

    @ManyToOne
    private Alias alias;
}
```

And I would like to make something like the following JPQL query

```
SELECT conversation FROM Conversation conversation WHERE :sender MEMBER OF conversation.aliasA.recipients AND conversation.adId=:adID
```

Where `:sender` is in the key of my Map. The `MEMBER OF` keyword however only seems to work with Sets and not with Maps. I believe that JPA 2.0 should offer the `KEY` keyword, but this doesn't seem to be implemented in OpenJPA yet. Is there an alternative to this?

Update: Added information to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While axtavt's answer gave me the hint I needed, the answer was actually, that the error checking in IntelliJ 10.5.4 is not to be trusted in this case.

The `KEY` keyword does indeed work and the correct query was

```
SELECT conversation FROM Conversation conversation JOIN conversation.aliasA.recipients recipients WHERE KEY(recipients) = :senderAddress AND conversation.adId=:adID
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `VALUE` keyword that should allow you to something like this:

```
SELECT c FROM Conversation c JOIN c.aliasA a JOIN a.recepients r 
WHERE VALUE(r) = :sender AND conversation.adId=:adID
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `VALUE` keyword doesn't seem to be implemented in OpenJPA. Are you sure this should work?

Comment: Addendum: I also realized I actually would like to check for the content of the key of my map. The `KEY` keyword seems to also not have been implemented so far however.